# VBA Selenium - Text not pulling through from Xpath

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have written some VBA code to pull out some stats from a webpage. Almost all of it pulls through, but the name of the player is the only bit of information that is not being returned. I've tried the different versions of the name (full, short, first, last), but nothing seems to work and yet. The code is exactly the same as all the other information that is being returned. I've been using the XPath to reach the text because I've found the website changes the class name from time to time. This is my code:

```vb
Set ch = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
ch.AddArgument "--headless"
ch.Get "https://www.euroleaguebasketball.net/eurocup/game-center/2023-24/cedevita-olimpija-ljubljana-joventut-badalona/U2023/12/#boxscore"

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
Rw = 1
Base = "//*[@id='main']/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/"
For Rw = 1 To 20
    Exists = ch.FindElementsByXPath(Base & "div[1]/div[" & Rw & "]/span").Count
    
    If Exists > 0 Then
    sht.Cells(Rw, 1) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[1]/div[" & Rw & "]/span").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 2) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[1]/div[" & Rw & "]/a/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 3) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[1]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 4) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[1]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 5) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[2]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 6) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[2]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 7) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[3]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 8) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[3]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 9) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[4]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 10) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[4]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 11) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[5]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 12) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[5]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 13) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[5]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[3]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 14) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[6]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 15) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[6]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 16) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[6]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[3]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 17) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[7]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 18) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[7]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 19) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[8]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 20) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[8]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 21) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[9]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[1]").Text
    sht.Cells(Rw, 22) = ch.FindElementByXPath(Base & "div[2]/div[9]/div[" & Rw & "]/div/div[2]").Text

    End If
Next Rw
```

I am getting this:

[image: Excel Screenshot]

So the numbers are pulling in (I can fix the formatting) but the name is just blank.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use absolute `XPATH`, it's impossible to read your code with it and absolute paths are difficult to support. Change of one element in `DOM` that is present in `XPATH` tree would break your locator.

Instead of it, use shortened 'relative' declaration.

[Reference](https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html)

For example, unique locator for your `Base` variable is `//div[contains(@class, 'is-active')]//*[contains(@class, 'game-box-scores-table-grouped-tab_tableGrouped_')]`

It's easily to find it - you go to your base element and look at it's attributes. You see that it has class that seemed to be unique. You search for class `game-box-scores-table-grouped-tab_tableGrouped_'` and you get 2 elements. But you need only 1. You look on it's parents and you see, that one of parents of your table has class `is-active`, it points to visible table.

We got short and explanative `Base`. Then we looking for player name.
Inspecting element we see that it has unique class part `playerFullName` that belongs to name only.

Xpath locator for it is `//*[contains(@class, 'playerFullName’)]`

So we need just to get elements array, using this selector and get needed row by index (`Rw` in your case)

```vb
Base = "//div[contains(@class, 'is-active')]//*[contains(@class, 'game-box-scores-table-grouped-tab_tableGrouped_')]/"
For Rw = 1 To 20
    // your code
    sht.Cells(Rw, yourCell) = ch.FindElements(By.XPath(Base & "/*[contains(@class, 'playerFullName’)]"))(Rw).Text
```

Comment: Thank you @Yaroslavm for the advice on the path. I still couldn't get it to work at first, but I have discovered that is because playerFullName is empty unless the window is maximised and because I had added the headless argument it was not maximised. If I changed the argument to 'start-maximized' I was returning the playerFullName. It was a slight challenge using your advice to get the rest of the data, because they all live in tableStatCell, but I think I have managed it